# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'navigation.dispatch')

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to the first page after user logout!
and getting this error:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'navigation.dispatch').

my action creator code is as follows:

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import {applyMiddleware as dispatch} from "redux";

export const userRemove = (navigation) => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('user');
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'First',
        props: {}
    });
    navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
};
```

I have called this action from sideBar of component. The component code is correct since that AsyncStorage.removeItem('user') is working correctly!
sorry for bad grammar. I can't write in english better than this [error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcilU.png)

my component code here:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Container,
    Content,
    Footer,
    FooterTab,
    Button,
    Icon
} from 'native-base';
import {userRemove} from '../actions/sideBarAction';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";

class SideBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    logout() {
        userRemove(this.props.navigation);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    ...
                </Content>
                <Footer>
                    <FooterTab>
                        <Button onPress={this.logout.bind(this)}>
                            <Icon name="logout"/>
                        </Button>
                    </FooterTab>
                </Footer>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        username: state.home.username,
        password: state.home.password,
        score: state.home.score,
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return Object.assign({dispatch: dispatch}, 
    bindActionCreators(userRemove, dispatch));
};

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SideBar);
```

Comment: Are you sure your userRemove is receiving the argument `navigation`? You can check this by console.log(navigation). It shouldn't print undefined.

Comment: you're right! it prints undefined. so what should i do? why it's undefined? edited: component code added

Comment: Try console.log inside the logout function, if that function has the this.props.navigation available in it or if it is undefined.

Comment: it's undefined too! this problem occurs anywhere that i used dispatch to navigate. my navigations without dispatch working fine. is there any possibility relying to redux [or react-redux] bug or version incompatibility?

Comment: redux 4.0.0 react-redux 5.0.7 react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.57.1

Comment: I do not exactly know what's causing th issue. The navigation doesn't seem to reach inside that function for some reason. One thing you can do is instead of making the logout function a separate file, why not do the navigation action displatch within the file itself, and using this.props.navigation instead of passing it around between functions. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your component added to you main navigator? If not see if you can add.

You can also wrap your component with `withNavigation` function from `react-navigation`. That will make sure you have valid `navigation` prop.

```
import { withNavigation } from react-navigation;

...

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withNavigation(SideBar));
```

Alternatively, you may pass `this.props.navigation` from parent component too.

Comment: i edited your code snippet and changed "withRouter" to "withNavigation" as you said